# Explain BM25 algorithm

Tags: search-engine, ranking

Explain to me [the BM25 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25). Currently, I'm using classic [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) which isn't quite good.

Comment: Explain you? Lol.. read books they explain better.